# Cannot match function declaration for template function in template class

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider

```
template<class Y> struct foo
{
    template <class ForwardIt>
    foo(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last);
};
```

In order to implement the constructor, I've written

```
template<class Y, class ForwardIt> foo(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    // ToDo - code here
}
```

But this generates a compile error to the effect that it cannot match that definition with a declaration.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. First, you're missing the name of the class in the function definition outside of the class's body, which basically means you're declaring a freestanding function that has nothing to do with the class or its member function (in this case it is illegal because your function does not have a return type hence cannot be a freestanding function).

Secondly, you must use distinct `template` declarations for your class template parameters and member function  template parameters.

You need:

```
template<class Y>
template<class ForwardIt>
foo<Y>::foo(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    // ToDo - code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class Y>
template<class ForwardIt>
foo<Y>::foo(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
}
```

is the correct way to define this.